# How to calculate the completion percentage relation by start and finish dates

Tags: ms-project, gantt, ms-project-2016

I need to calculate the current date in relation to the start and end dates of a task and would expect to see a field that shows the completion percentage.
Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27968064/1509853) Question or [this](https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/perentage-calculation-between-two-dates.4502/#post-23538) explanation `(today - start date)/(End date- Start date)`.

Comment: I removed your second question. If you have a second question, you should ask it in a separate Question, linking if necessary.

Comment: They are linked with each other so I put them together

Comment: Your call if you want to add it back, but it seemed to me that the two questions could each be answered in isolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the percentage of a task that should be done based on the current date and working time (e.g. the project calendar), customize a number field with this formula:

```
IIf( [Start] > Date(), 0, IIf( [Finish] < Date(), 1, ProjDateDiff( [Start], Date()) / [Duration]))
```

Note: answer was updated to reflect OP's correction to handle future tasks.

Comment: thanks !-) I customized a text field with `100 * IIf( [Start] > Date(), 0, IIf( [Finish] < Date(), 1, ProjDateDiff( [Start], Date()) / [Duration])) & "%"`